# Dataframe mean returns empty series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows. I want to get the mean of column `pred1_score` as a number. However, my attempt returns an empty series. Could you please help me?

```
>>> df1.head()
   Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 0.1 compare  ... preds_score pred1_score pred2_score
0         0.0            0      //  ...      0.6045      0.6195      0.5272
1         1.0            1      //  ...      0.6045      0.5403      0.4759
2         2.0            2      //  ...      0.6045      0.3759      0.3636
3         3.0            3      //  ...      0.6045      0.5923      0.5187
4         4.0            4      //  ...      0.6045      0.5926      0.4553

[5 rows x 13 columns]
>>> df1[["pred1_score"]].mean()
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I also tried:

```
df1[['pred1_score']].astype(float).mean()
```

But it throws:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'pred1_score'
```

Which could be the column head.

Comment: It's not returning empty list, that's empty series. I'm not able to reproduce it, you can try to calculate `mean` on series using `df1['pred1_score'].mean()`

Comment: @ThePyGuy a series containing an empty list or array. Anyways, it returns `could not convert string to float: '0.61950.54030.37590.59230.59260.55650.35620.59720.59620.69740.15710.64500.48990.36590.2993`

Comment: That's the problem, `mean` works only on numerical values, try to convert it to numeric first then calculate the mean. `pd.to_numeric(df1['pred1_score'], errors='coerce').mean()`

Comment: @ThePyGuy, thanks, now it works! The main problem was that I concatenated several datafame files using `cat` and it kept the headers between the lines...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `df1[["pred1_score"]].mean()` please try `df1.pred1_score.astype('float').mean()`

Comment: thanks, it returns `could not convert string to float: '0.61950.54030.37590.59230.59260.55650.35620.59720.59620.69740.15710.64500.48990.36590.2993`

Comment: You have to first convert it to float using `df1.pred1_score.astype(float)`
then execute the above code

Comment: How did you generate your data frame? It looks like you have non numerical values in your column. What is the output of `df1["pred1_score"].dtype` ? If not float, but object, this means you have invalid rows in your column.

Comment: I have updated the answer to address the non-numeric field issue